# При наведении на 1 уровень меню открываются все уровни меню

Tags: меню, dropdown, навигация

Готовая тема http://www.webyzona.com/templates/flippy/index.html

Меню 3 уровня открывается при наведении на меню первого уровня пример -  http://festivaly.com.cy/test.html# (вкладка услуги) . На чистом коде все работает как надо и не открывается сразу все уровни. Как понять, какой код открывает все уровни?

Comment: http://take.ms/lY865 вот скриншот где все работает

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).fadeIn(500);
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).fadeOut(100);
    });
});` Вот этот код. Из custome.js

Comment: Как его поправить, что бы он работал как надо?